# How to test if byte[] is a SHA512withRSA signature?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, digital-signature, sha512

I am creating an RSA signature on Android like this:

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA");

    // With what private key?
    signature.initSign(privateKey);

    // What document to Sign?
    signature.update(BYdocument);

    // Give me the signed document
    byte[] BYsignedDocument = signature.sign();
```

Document and signature are packed in separated files. User must input the signature manually. This is why I am trying to stop them from inputting something that is not a signature.

How do I check, if the signature `BYsignedDocument`  is actually a signature without the need of the public key or the document?

Comment: Why do you think you can check a signature without the public key **or** the document?

Comment: I am not checking the validity of signature. I am checking if the byte[] i am receiving in fact is a signature and not some garbage inside byte[]. Is there an indicator inside the `BYsignedDocument`  that tells me what it is?

Comment: This is more something for cryptography (crypto.stackexchange.com). Note that java and android are keywords, but that the code is only used to generate a standard signature.

Comment: The hash is 512 bytes. The signature in Java is bigger than that. This is why I suspect there must be a header. If the signature in fact would only be the hash in this implementation, I could just simply test for size (would be good enough).

Comment: *The signature in Java is bigger than [the hash]* - RSA signing encrypts not only the hash but a bigger ASN.1 structure which also denotes the hashing algorithm. Furthermore that structure is padded before encryption. Thus, it is no surprise the signature is bigger than the naked hash.

Comment: Would you maybe know how to get the Hashing algorithm out of the `BYsignedDocument`? i.e. How to create a Signature object from byte[] in this case. That would solve my problem good enough.

Comment: @KrNeki You can only get the type and hash value out of a (raw) signature using the public key (or, for PKCS#1 v1.5, you could regenerate the signature using the private key and the data)... If you could extract is otherwise you would have broken RSA...

Comment: Can you maybe tell me how to get the "type" from a (raw) signature using the public key? (So, I would still not be verifying what is signed, but only verifying who is the signer). To clarify - my signature is separated from the document.

Comment: As you want to extract information from a signature, you should switch to using a more verbose signature type, e.g. a CMS signature container. Such a signature container provides quite a lot of information even without the need to use a key.

Comment: That would make sense, however the size of the signature is the main concern. This time it is a proof-of-concept only, in the future I will probably strip down the signature to the bare minimum (minimum verbosity). And I will maybe just add one byte myself to check if it is a signature.

Comment: As I now found out, the size of the signature in RSA is the same as the size of the key which signed it (so unrelated to the hash). It is only important, that the key size is bigger than the hash used. [Source](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19094/verifying-signature-owner-without-verifying-the-actual-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to reliably detect an RSA signature. If you have many RSA signatures then you may see some bias in the first bit (s) because of the calculation being performed using the modulus. In that sense you could check if some byte arrays are *not* signatures, but not the other way around.

For more information, see [this Q/A on cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/204/1172), especially [the answer of Poncho](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/13105/1172)

Comment: It's about encryption, but the same goes for signature generation in this case.